# Web apps bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth

I'm wondering if there are studies regarding bandwidth usage of websites. Most modern websites use background Ajax requests to reload content from time to time to refresh information. Of course it takes bandwidth but I would be interested in a link to a website reporting common website bandwidth usage when you keep a web page.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in knowing how much bandwidth specific sites use, you can download the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) webpage debugger and use the 'net' tab to see each request your browser makes and how large the response is.

Since I started typing this message I got 3 responses from webapps.stackexchange.com and they wereneach 26 bytes.

Comment: Yep I know how to it myself, the goal is to get already existing information

Comment: @radius: you mean a site which has statistics like "the average gmail users uses 10mb bandwidth over 10minutes"?

Comment: Yes but only when they are doing nothing on the website. If you leave gmail open it will check for the mail even if you don't do anything. This result should be almost the same for every user on most website I guess